# how to migrate lvm mirrorlog from physical partition

Tags: lvm, mdadm, mirroring

Output from: sudo lvs --all -o +devices

```
root                        hp03 mwa-ao  18.62g                    root_mlog        100.00         root_mimage_0(0),root_mimage_1(0)                        
[root_mimage_0]             hp03 iwi-ao  18.62g                                                    /dev/sda3(0)                                             
[root_mimage_1]             hp03 iwi-ao  18.62g                                                    /dev/sdc3(0)                                             
[root_mlog]                 hp03 mwi-ao   4.00m                                     100.00         root_mlog_mimage_0(0),root_mlog_mimage_1(0)              
[root_mlog_mimage_0]        hp03 iwi-ao   4.00m                                                    /dev/sdd3(0)                                             
[root_mlog_mimage_1]        hp03 iwi-ao   4.00m                                                    /dev/sdb3(0)
```

/dev/sdb3 and /dev/sdd3 are surplus to my needs, and I want to remove them.
As my mirrorlog is mirrored, I feel happy having it on /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdc3.
I try to move the mirror log elsewhere:

```
# pvmove --name /dev/hp03/root_mlog_mimage_1 /dev/sdb3
Skipping mirror image LV root_mlog_mimage_1
All data on source PV skipped. It contains locked, hidden or non-top level LVs only.
No data to move for hp03
```

No dice.  How can I unlock/unhide these volumes so that they can be moved?
I hope the answer is not, remove the mirror and add it back, as there is several TB of data that I need to do this for.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this http://www.sandelman.ca/mcr/blog/2012/02/05#lvm_mirroring__the_right_way

First try:

```
lvconvert -m 1 --mirrorlog mirrored --alloc anywhere
```

"--alloc anywhere" should enable mirrorlogs to be on same PV, then try pvmove.
Perhaps it can be done in one command:

```
lvconvert -m 1 --mirrorlog mirrored --alloc anywhere /dev/hp03/root /dev/sda3 /dev/sdc3
```